# Using polling in jeromq

Tags: android, zeromq, jeromq

I am learning to use zeromq polling in android . I am polling on a req socket and a sub socket in the android program(client). So that this client can receive both reply messages from the server and also published messages.

My polling is not working. Both the req socket and the publish socket does not get polled in. If i don't use polling both the sockets receive the message.

I tried searching online but could not find anything relevant. 
The client code is this :

```
    public void run()
   {
    ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
    ZMQ.Socket reqsocket = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
    ZMQ.Socket subsocket =context.socket(ZMQ.SUB);
    reqsocket.connect("tcp://10.186.3.174:8081");
    subsocket.connect("tcp://10.186.3.174:8083");
    subsocket.subscribe("".getBytes());
    byte[] receivedmessage;
    Poller poller=context.poller();
    poller.register(reqsocket,Poller.POLLIN);
    poller.register(subsocket,Poller.POLLIN);

    reqsocket.send(msg.getBytes(),0); 

    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
     {

        if(poller.pollin(0))
        {
            receivedmessage=s.recv(0);

        }
          if(poller.pollin(0))
          {
            receivedmessage=subsocket.recv(0);

          }
   }
    s.close();
    context.term();
```

}

Am i missing out something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there are 3 problems with this.
The main one is you need to call `poller.poll()` as the first thing inside the `while` loop. This is why you are not getting *any* messages.

The next issue is that you're checking the same index for both sockets: I expect the second `if` statement needs to be

```
if(poller.pollin(1))
```

Lastly, the req socket requires a send before **every** receive, so the call to send needs to be inside the while loop, and before the `poller.poll()` you just added above :)

Comment: How can I use jeromq into android? it's the same like Java Se? I was looking how to do it and got nothing.